# Update or refresh using datasource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I load my data from `ms-access` database to `listbox`.. all I want to do is update or refresh my `listbox datasource` when I click on my update button. then this is the code i use for method then call the `DataLoadListBox()` on `form_load event`, and update `button_click event`..

```
private BindingList<mylist> myList = new BindingList<mylist>();

private void DataLoadListBox()
{
    string query = "select * from myItem order by itemname";
    OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, Conn());
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    cmd.Fill(dt, "myItem");
    DataTable datTable = dt.Tables[0];
    foreach (DataRow dtRow in datTable.Rows)
    {
        myList.Add(new mylist() { id = dtRow["ID"].ToString(), itemname = dtRow["itemname"].ToString() });
    }
    mylb.DisplayMember = "itemname";
    mylb.DataSource = myList;
    mylb.ValueMember = "id";
    Conn().Close();
}
```

then when the `textbox` text has been fill with what I want I pushed the update `button_click` event which coded like below

```
OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("update myItem set itemname = @itemname where ID = @ID", Conn());
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemname", itemname.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", itemid.Text));
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
// start updating the listbox
myList.Clear();
mylb.DataSource = null;
mylb.Items.Clear();
mylb.Refresh();
mylb.Update();
mylb.DataSource = myList;
DataLoadListBox();
// none of above working, the listbox datasource not getting update
```

the problem is i don't get my `listbox datasource` updated, what I'm doing wrong here? How do I make this work?

Comment: _Well_, your question isn't very clear. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] first..

Comment: sorry, i'll edit my post..thanks for mentioning..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to close the connection in DataLoadListBox. Do you open it in button_click or is it at least open when reaching that code?

If not your missing a minimum of Exception Handling here. If ExecuteNonQuery is throwing an Exception you are simply ignoring it at the moment.